# Google Smartlock: what to do when PromiseStatus: pending via Javascript in console

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, google-smartlockpasswords

we are integrating Google Smartlock. Every time we run the JS code to enable Smart lock on 1 screen it does nothing at all. And when we trigger it manually we only see this in console log.

```
Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}
```

javascript is like this

```
<script>
        window.onload=function(e){
            var debug = true;
            var always = function() { console.log('Promise resolved: but dont understand how should process: we want/need to login') }
            navigator.credentials.get({password: true, unmediated: true, }).then(function(cred) { 
            if (cred) {
                if (cred.type == 'password') {  
                var form = new FormData();
                cred.additionalData = form;
                var url = 'domain.com/login';
                fetch(url, {method: 'POST', credentials: cred }).then(function(response) { 
                    if (response.status == 202) {
                      if (debug) { console.log('Login success; reload stopped'); exit; }
                      window.location.reload();
                    }
                    if (debug) { console.log('Server status: ' + response.status); }
                    return;
                  }).catch(function(err) { console.log('Smartlock Ajax error:'+ err); 
                  }).then(always, always);
                } // can add federated here
            } else if (typeof cred === "undefined") {
                // user clicks cancel or no credentials found
                var expiry = new Date(); expiry.setDate(expiry.getDate() + (1/3600*30));
                document.cookie="dontshowagain=true; expires=" + expiry.toGMTString();
            }
            });

        }
        </script>
```

**Question**: Does anyone know what is happening here?

I tested with 1 saved passwd, with 2 saved passwd's. We do see the small key icon next to the URL in Chrome. But it doesn't popup or do anything.

Help/advise appreciated

[image]

[image]

References: 
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6160273?hl=en

Comment: yes, while a promise is pending, it's valued would be undefined - as you have posted only partial code, there's no way to know what's happening with the response for instance, nor can I see any `.catch` to at least show any errors you may be getting

Comment: let me add it. 1 sec. DONE

Comment: The problem we have/jad with the above code is the distinction between: no login information found + user clicks the cancel / cross on login

Comment: @JaromandaX did this help you? Any feedback welcome .. still stuck

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're requesting `unmediated: true` which forces the browser to not show the account selector UI.

When you have more than one credentials stored or one credential that requires user mediation, `get(...)` returns `undefined` unless you allow the mediation (`unmediated: false` which is default).

***Note:*** Your credentials should require mediation when the user signs out of an account (`navigator.credentials.requireUserMediation()`).

Comment: thx I did have it without before. I just removed the unmediated but not sure this helps .... I think what I dont understand is the difference between a user who dismisses the login window || not finding any credentials. When a user dismissed we dont want to bug them again. How would I solve a user who `does not want` to login?

Comment: What do you mean by: "navigator.credentials.requireUserMediation()"

Comment: And sorry for the number 3 ;P But is there a simple method to maybe reset the Promise on page load so this error of Pending can not occur?

Comment: The user is far more likely to hit "never" on the save credential dialog if they don't want to interact with Smart Lock.

Comment: There's no difference in response to `get(...)` whether there are no credentials or the user hits cancel.

This shouldn't need to be a concern to the app. You should be able to store a cookie that you've (a) attempted to request a credential without mediation & (b) requested a credential with mediation. Then you shouldn't ask again.